# How do I iterate circular linked list with `NULL` head at first in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to build a circular list in ANSI C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node * ptr;
typedef struct node {
   int data;
   ptr next;
}item;

void add2list(ptr *head, int num);

int main() {
    ptr h = NULL;
    add2list(&h, 1);
    add2list(&h, 5);
    add2list(&h, 3);

    return 0;
}

void add2list(ptr *head, int num) {
    ptr p1, p2, t, temp;

    t = (ptr) malloc(sizeof(item));

    if(!t) {
        printf("not enough memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    t -> data = num;
    p1 = *head;

    while( (p1 -> next != *head) && (p1 -> data < num) ) { //problem in this line
        p2 = p1;
        p1 = p1 -> next;
    }

    if(*head == p1) {
        temp = *head;
        *head = t;
        (*head) -> next = temp;
    } else {
        p2 -> next = t;
        t -> next = p1;
    }
}
```

`add2list()` function is supposed to add a new member to the linked list based on the value of the `num` argument. The list is supposed to be in ascending order. With this code I get the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)`. After debugging I found out that the error is thrown because of the code `(p1 -> next != *head)` in the `while` loop. I think the error occurs because if `p1` points to `*head` and `*head` is itself `NULL` then `p1 -> next` is not good. But then how do I properly iterate through the list?

Comment: At the first call *head is NULL, so p1->next dereferences NULL. You can easily check that with a debugger. Are you sure you want a circular list, not a linear list!? Do you mind sharing the reason to use a circular list?

Comment: I need to build a circular list as part of the assignment in my C class. Do you have any advice how to go about iteration in such case? Maybe iterating just with head is too complicated and I need to create a tail? I'd rather do it with just a head though

Comment: You can do `while(p1 != NULL  &&  p->next != *head  && ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void add2list(ptr *head, int num) {
    ptr p1, p2, t, temp;

    t = (ptr) malloc(sizeof(item));

    if(!t) {
        printf("not enough memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    t -> data = num;

    if(!(*head)){
         *head = t;
         t->next = t;
         return;
    }

    ///... rest of your code in case head is not NULL
```

That way, you deal with the case `head == NULL`, by giving head the address of t ; i added t->next = t, so your list is circular from its creation.

Comment: true, i edited. btw, the code is incorrect it won't create a proper circular list, i'm modifying it to have it work properly.

Comment: @m.raynal a typo problem in `if{!(*head)){`... shall be `if (!(*head)) {`.